# Problem displaying the data from my 'artists' table with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I do not manage to display the data from my database (I'm working with Laragon).

I already tried to change some names (variables etc.) here and there but I can't find where come from the problem.

I was able to display nothing first so I needed to change:

resources\views\artist\index.php  ->  resources\views\artist**s**\index.**blade**.php

I probalby need to change more things in the code but I don't know where.

VIEW (views\artists\index.blade.php)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Liste des artistes')

@section('content')
    <h1>Liste des {{ $resource }}</h1>

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($artists as $artist)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $artist->firstname }}</td>
                <td>{{ $artist->lastname }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

ROUTES (routes\web.php)

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('artists', 'ArtistController@index');
```

CONTROLLER (Controllers\ArtistController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Artist;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArtistController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        /*
         Take the artist from the db
         and send it to a specific template
         */
        $artists = Artist::all();

        return view('artists.index',
            [
            'artists' => $artists,
            'resource' => 'artistes',
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Artist  $artist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Artist $artist)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Artist  $artist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Artist $artist)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Artist  $artist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Artist $artist)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Artist  $artist
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Artist $artist)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

DATABASE (database\ArtistsTableSeeder.php)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ArtistsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $artists = [
            ['firstname'=>'Bob','lastname'=>'Sull'],
            ['firstname'=>'Marc','lastname'=>'Flynn'],
            ['firstname'=>'Fred','lastname'=>'Durand'],
        ];

        foreach ($artists as $a) {
            DB::table('artists')->insert([
                'firstname' => $a['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $a['lastname'],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing who get displayed on my browser when I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/artists` is:

```
**Liste des Artistes** 

Firstname Lastname
```

But nothing from the content of my Artistes table is displayed.

Comment: have you checked if the database table actually have any data ?

Comment: Yes, I can display them in the mysql command line.

Comment: remove             'resource' => 'artistes', just to test you are not overriding the $artistes variable

Comment: When I do this, I get the following error message:

 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: resource (View: C:\randomModifiedPath\resources\views\artists\index.blade.php)

Comment: remove it from the view too

Comment: When I do this, I only get displayed:

Firstname   Lastname 

With no data.

Comment: check for db connection

Comment: Check to see if your table name is "artist" or "artists". It should be the plural - "artists"

Comment: Ok. I'm checking right now the .env and the .env.example files. The name of my table is "artists".
In my vendor\.env file 

The DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD look correctly configured in the .env file

Comment: Try ```var_dump($artists)``` in the controller to see if the $artists variable is not empty

Comment: where is your model (Artist) ?

Comment: give permission to access the field names of database (Check with Model give fillable)

Comment: var_dump($artists) gives me lots of text. $artists seems not empty.

Comment: Here the path of Artist.php file :

app/Artist.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much guys, the problems was that I needed to change the names of my columns...

FirstName LastName to Firstname Lastname

The data get displayed properly now.